# Get parent vCenter of a VM using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the parent vCenter of a VM using PowerCLI.

As per the documentation [https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Aria-Operations/8.12/Using-Operations/GUID-E68037C7-7FC3-41F6-9AAC-1DE6D0D36213.html%22](https://stackoverflow.com)

The parent vCenter key is "summary|parentVcenter". But when I try to get the value.
It says `"Could not find OMStatKey with name 'summary|parentVcenter' "`

The command that I used is `Get-OMStat -Resource TestVM01 -Key "summary|parentVcenter"`

I want to know why its through error where the key value is correct